# How many ways to perform task which will take long time in android?

Tags: android, service, task

Different ways in android to perform tasks which will take long time.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines) and [work manager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics)